# How can I store id of products in an array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Let's say I have a shopping cart and I get data from db by this code:

```
$cart_id = $_GET['cart_id'];
$get_add = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cart_id = '$cart_id'";
$run_add = mysqli_query($con,$get_add);
$cart_items = [];
$total_price_to_pay = 0;
while ($row_results = mysqli_fetch_array($run_add)){
    $item = array(
        'table_id' => $row_results['table_id'],
        'cart_id' => $row_results['cart_id'],
        'pro_id' => $row_results['product_id'],
        'pro_title' => $row_results['product_title'],
        'pro_price' => $row_results['product_price'],
        'pro_img' => $row_results['product_image'],
        'pro_supplier' => $row_results['product_supplier'],
        'qty' => $row_results['qty'],
        'cart_ip' => $row_results['cart_ip'],
        'pro_total' => $row_results['qty']*$row_results['product_price'],
    );
    $total_price_to_pay +=  $row_results['qty']*$row_results['product_price'];
    $cart_items[] = $item;
}
```

And for showing results I did this:

```
    <form method='POST' action=''>
<?php foreach ($cart_items as $cart) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='pro_id' value='".$cart['pro_id']."'>
    <h4><a href=''>".$cart['pro_title']."</a></h4>
    <p>".$cart['pro_supplier']."</p>
    <select name='quantites'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5</option>
    </select>";
} ?>
    <input name='update' type='submit' value='UPDATE'></input>
</form>
```

As you can see I added this input hidden which contains the id of each product:

```
<input type='hidden' name='pro_id' value='".$cart['pro_id']."'>
```

Now I want to store all the id of products in an array instead of this above line.

For exmaple `$cart_ids = []`

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: You can store pro_ids in an array of hidden inputs by naming them with `[]` like - `<input type='hidden' name='pro_ids[]' value='".$cart['pro_id']."'>` each time.

Comment: `name='pro_id[0]'` or `name='product[0][id]'` is good notation to use to build arrays of form data with PHP.

Comment: sidenote: this `$item = array(...` is redundant. You could just use `$row_results` and add the `$row_results['pro_total'] = $row_results['qty']*$row_results['product_price']` to it.

Comment: @Mr.Blue Cannot use [] for reading

Comment: You're doing `[]` in php variable - `$pro_ids[]`. Html name - `name="pro_ids[]"` -  is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_column()` function to get an array of a column in a 2-dimensional array:

```
$cart_ids = array_column($cart_items, 'pro_id');
```